# Confusion around Newton's third law of motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration

I'm really confused about Newton's third law which states that "every action has an equal and opposite reaction." Which means if an object A applies a force on object B then object B will apply the same amount of force on object A but in the opposite direction.
The problem I have is with the equal statement, the question is: if an object A has a small mass $m_{A}$ and a small acceleration $a_{A}$ applies a force $F_{A}$ on object B that has a bigger mass $m_{B}$ and a bigger acceleration $a_{B}$ (resulted because of object A's applied force) violate Newton's third law of motion which states that $F_{A} = m_{A} × a_{A}$ and $F_{B} = m_{B} × a_{B}$ must have the same magnitude? Or is my scenario an impossibility to begin with?

Comment: Still unclear. If you push someone, you will accelerate backwards. Just try with a wall of infinite (at least very high) mass.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if i pushed a wall wouldn't my acceleration be 0 ? As I won't move at all (hence no acceleration) when trying to push that massive object thus no Force applied by myself (which I find strange).

Comment: Go to the nearest wall, stand upright and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an impossibility. You are imagining a situation that can't happen. Just as if I imagined that I was levitating in the air without touching the ground, and claimed that this violates the idea of gravity being present.

The answer could of course be that the idea of gravity may be wrong - or the answer could be that my imagined scenario is impossible. The only way to know this is to test for the presence of gravity in separate tests. The experimental evidence of gravity convinces us so, so we believe gravity to always be present, also in my imagined scenario. The same is the case for your Newton's 3rd law: Experimental evidence has never failed to show us that this law holds true - so we assume it to hold true in your scenario as well. It must be something else than Newton's 3rd law which is at fault in your scenario.

In your case, if a force causes an acceleration, then it must fulfill $F=ma$. If that force is a reaction to another force by Newton's 3rd law, then naturally, the $ma$ will fit that as well. Were the $ma$ value different, then it wasn't that force, which caused it. Claiming that it definitely *is* that force, which caused it, is the impossible part of your scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Your scenario is an impossibility to begin with. If $a_{1},m_{1} < a_{2},m_{2}$ respectively, then $a_{1}*m_{1} < a_{2}*m_{2}$ which violates newton's third law.

Instead, assuming that $F_{1} = F_{2}$, then we see that if $m_{1} < m_{2}$, then $a_{2} < a_{1}$. Thus, if I push on the wall I will experience a greater acceleration than the wall because I'm less massive and we are sharing the same force. The harder you push, the more you will feel it pushing against you because you're so much less massive than the wall.